# Can't connect to Samsung clx-3175 laser printer

Tags: 12.04, printing, samsung

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04. My computer no longer recognises my laser printer - Samsung CLX-3175 - and will not install the drivers, refusing to run the scripts downloaded from the Samsung site. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add the exact command you ran to install the drivers, as well as the output in your question, and mark it as code. This will help us better help you. I have had good luck with Samsung's drivers on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

This printer should work with the Samsung CLX-3175 Foomatic/foo2qpdl driver included with Ubuntu.

Go to system-config-printer (System -> Administration -> Printing in GNOME classic, Gear icon at the upper right of the screen -> Printers in Unity), right click your Printer and select Properties > click Change... next to the Make and Model field to see the available drivers and change it to Samsung CLX-3175.

Normally your printer should automatically get set up with this driver when first connected with USB.

Comment: Some screenshots would make this answer totally awesome!